# Why SQL UNION can combine two columns which have different data type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union, popsql

I already have branch_id (type INT), client_name (type VARCHAR (30).

All I know that when we use UNION operator, the columns must also have similar data types. The problem is why I can combine it with two columns which have different data type like the code below but still don't get any error? (DBSM: MySQL, SQL editor: PopSQL)

**Code:**

```
SELECT client_name
FROM client
UNION
SELECT branch_id
FROM branch_supplier;
```

**Result:**

```
client_name
--------------------
Dunmore Highschool
Lackawana Country
FedEx
John Daly Law, LLC
Scranton Whitepages
Times Newspaper
1
2
3
4
```

Thank you for your attention

Comment: MySQL allows many things that aren't allowed by the SQL standard. It will automatically convert datatypes in many cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL automatically converts datatypes when necessary. So your query is treated as if you'd written:

```
SELECT client_name
FROM client
UNION
SELECT CAST(branch_id AS CHAR)
FROM branch_supplier;
```